# Nginx reverse proxy subdirectory to root

Tags: nginx

So. I am using Nginx as a load balancer to load traffic between couple of instances.

Let's say my Nginx loadbalancer is at platform.staging.com (example).

I am trying to redirect traffic from

```
platform.staging.com/sync
```

To one of these:

```
sync1.staging.com:12345
sync2.staging.com:12345
```

Notice that what I am trying to achieve is to have /sync part stripped down and requests to sync instances should have path /.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
upstream sync-cluster {
  ip_hash;
  server sync1.staging.com:12345;
  server sync2.staging.com:12345;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy;
  server_name platform.staging.com;

  location /sync {
    proxy_pass http://sync-cluster;
  }
}
```

In the logs I can see:

```
2014/01/14 23:20:38 [error] 2385#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XXX.XX.XXX, server: platform.staging.com, request: "GET /sync HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://X.X.X.XXX:12345/sync", host: "platform.staging.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a rewrite before doing the proxy pass, I'll assume you are going to preserve what's after `/sync`, hope this works for you

```
location ^~ /sync(.*) {
  rewrite ^ $1;
  proxy_pass ...;
}
```